# Dinotrace installation

Tags: software-installation, system, emacs

was trying to install dinotrace viewer. instructions at: http://www.veripool.org/projects/dinotrace/wiki/Installing

got the following error in make install command:

```
*** Lisp files not installed, you may want to
*** cd lisp ; make install
Type setenv DISPLAY :0.0 then dinotrace to test.
abhishek@abhishek-Inspiron-5520:~/Downloads/dinotrace-9.4d$
```

what do i need to do? i installed emacs using `sudo apt-get install emacs` but that doesn't help

Comment: Maybe you have to download some emacs lisp files (.el extension) to work with emacs and dinotrace.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Emacs lisp directory. If you don't know the name of this directory, in Emacs you can type `C-h v load-path <RET>` and that will list the directories that Emacs search for files to load. Look for the name of a directory beginning with "~/" or "/home/abhishek/": this is your Emacs lisp directory. Check if the files `dinotrace.el` and `sim-log.el` are in this directory. If they are not, you can obtain them from the dinotrace-9.4d/lisp/ directory that you have downloaded and simply copy them to your Emacs lisp directory.

**Update:**

If you don't have such a directory, you can create it and define it in your [.emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Emacs-Initialization.html#Emacs-Initialization) configuration file. For instance, in your home directory you can create a directory called `emacs`. Then edit your `.emacs` file and add this line to it:

> `(setq load-path (cons "~/emacs" load-path))`

This command adds your `~/emacs` directory to the existing load path.

Comment: what do you mean by "in emacs you can type"? this is how my emac window looks like:  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LesTcmHNFyOFJhb0Z5c3l4WUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal: Once you get this window, press the "control key" and the "h key" at the same time, then the "v key". It will appear a message saying "Describe variable:". Then you have to type `load-path` and press the "return key".

Comment: i did that...its not showing any directory with  "~/" or "/home/abhishek/". check this screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LesTcmHNFyaVl6Y08tcGlfbEk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See the "Update" to my answer.

Comment: edit .emacs file? what do you mean by that? which .emacs file? I am sorry if my question sounds dumb. I'm very new to Linux.

Comment: In your home directory, you should have a file called `.emacs`. You should open it with a text editor and add the above line to it. Remember that files whose names begin with a dot are hidden files, so you should use a "show hidden file" option.

Comment: there isn't a file called .emacs in my home directory. although there is .emacs.d folder. here arer the screenshots for it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LesTcmHNFyUmhxVThLZmFIUzQ/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LesTcmHNFydFNUR2t1VG16eGs/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LesTcmHNFyektuZXBXUEpNUTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you don't have a `.emacs` file, you can create it in your home directory, edit it and add the above lines to it.

Comment: followed the instructions as above and did the installation process from scratch.still getting the same error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8045132/

Comment: But, have you the files `dinotrace.el` and `sim-log.el` in your `~/emacs` directory? Is it something not working properly when you run dinotrace under emacs?

Comment: actually i am working on a software 'revkit' and it uses dinotrace to display simulation results. And maybe because dinotrace is not getting installed properly its showing 'dinotrace not found' error every time i ask for simulation results,